# Install Oracle Linux on Hp microserver G8 using ILO

Tags: hp, ilo, oracle-linux

I'm experiencing some problems installing Oracle Linux on a Microserve G8.
This server is headless, i'm using ILO for installation, and SSH for administration.
I can't install OL on this server because the mouse is useless: the cursor floats around the screen and i can't point the right button.
I have installed proxmox, slackware, freebsd and debian without problems.
I'm using a mac M1, with Chrome and safari, but tried even a X86 notebook, same issue.
using text mode installation is not an option, you can't manual partition the hd.
The ILO and BIOS are updated.
Please someone can help me?
Thank you in advance

EDIT: OL rel 9.2, i tried to google the problem, tried to change pc, browser, etc.

Comment: You omitted to mention WHICH VERSION of Oracle Linux this was and what you have already tried in order to resolve matter. This might help: https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Text_Installation_Intro-x86/

Comment: EDIT the question